# Navigate through a datagridview by showing record number

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Can anyone help me? I want to navigate through a datagridview - when I select a record from a datagridview, I want to know its record number, e.g record 2of3.

```
private void labelUpdate()
{
    if (hwdg.SelectedRows.Count >= inc)
    {
        hwdg.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = inc;
        hwdg.Rows[inc].Selected = true;
       //inc++;
        label27.Text = "Record" + (inc + 1) + " of " + ds2.Tables["tblComp"].Rows.Count;
    }
    else if(hwdg.SelectedRows.Count <= inc)
    {
        hwdg.Rows[inc - 1].Selected = true;
        label27.Text = "Record" + (inc + 1) + " of " + ds2.Tables["tblComp"].Rows.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `inc` come from?  We also need more details on your *expected* vs *actual* behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `hwdg.Rows[inc]["Id"]` since you have the index of the selected row - where "Id" is the name of your ID column in your data source.

ie:

```
private void labelUpdate()
{
    int id;
    if (hwdg.SelectedRows.Count >= inc)
    {
        hwdg.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = inc;
        hwdg.Rows[inc].Selected = true;
        id = (int)hwdg.Rows[inc]["Id"];
       //inc++;
        label27.Text = "Record" + (inc + 1) + " of " + ds2.Tables["tblComp"].Rows.Count;
    }
    else if(hwdg.SelectedRows.Count <= inc)
    {
        hwdg.Rows[inc - 1].Selected = true;
        id = (int)hwdg.Rows[inc - 1]["Id"];
        label27.Text = "Record" + (inc + 1) + " of " + ds2.Tables["tblComp"].Rows.Count;
    }
    // Do whatever you want to do with the id
}
```